# Migrate Windows Server 2012 R2 Data Center to a physical Windows Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, virtualization, migration, windows-server-2016

I am assisting a client to move from Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition to a physical machine.  The server is also running SQL Server which also needs to be migrated.

Anyone can suggest the appropriate tools to do this?

The situation is as follows:  Customer has the above mentioned machine running and wants to move it to a local server, the cost does not justify the low use of the machine, and a local server would be much more cost efficient.

I would have liked to migrate SQL Server and install it in a virtual machine but I am not sure this can be achieved.  Any suggestions on how to migrate this beast to a standard Windows Server?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is SQL Server the only service you want to migrate from the WS2012 R2 to WS2016 version?

Comment: It sounds like a simple backup and restore operation from SQL Management Studio? Whats using the database? Do you know/can you change credentials of database users?

Comment: There are so many factors to consider here it would be nearly impossible to give you quality advice in a single answer. We don’t know enough about your network and needs. You should consult with an industry professional to get some better direction. There are too many pitfalls with this. Connectivity, performance, backup, redundancy, security, compatibility, storage, etc.

Comment: Thank you all for replying.  The only difference will be the server, SQL remains the same but I waiting for answer of which specific version.  Full control of the server at the moment as far as I can tell.  I will worry about backups and redundancy later.  The clients may not use the server for long since it is going to be in use to clear inventory.   If you need more inforamtion please let me know